BitBucket: Container 'Build' exceeded memory limit
I'm having a hard time deploying my react app into production environment because it returns:
yarn build
yarn run v1.22.19
$ react-app-rewired build
Creating an optimized production build...
The build failed because the process exited too early. This probably means the system ran out of memory or someone called `kill -9` on the process.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.

This is my bitbucket pipeline file:
image: atlassian/default-image:3

pipelines:
  branches:
    stage: #STAGE
        - step:
            name: Build docker
            deployment: Staging
            services:
              - docker
            image: node:16-alpine
            size: 2x
            script:
              - export NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8192
              - yarn install
              - yarn build
              - echo $REACT_APP_AUTH
              - echo $REACT_APP_MEMBERSHIP
              - docker login -u $DOCKER_HUB_ID -p $DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD
              - docker build -t evoeccdocker/membership_front:stage --build-arg REACT_APP_AUTH=$REACT_APP_AUTH --build-arg REACT_APP_MEMBERSHIP=$REACT_APP_MEMBERSHIP --build-arg REACT_APP_PAYMENT=$REACT_APP_PAYMENT --build-arg REACT_APP_APPLICATION_ID=$REACT_APP_APPLICATION_ID --build-arg REACT_APP_APPLICATION_KEY=$REACT_APP_APPLICATION_KEY --build-arg REACT_APP_TINYMCE=$REACT_APP_TINYMCE --build-arg REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=$REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID --build-arg REACT_APP_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS=$REACT_APP_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS --build-arg REACT_APP_PAYMENT_PAGE_STORAGE_ENCRYPT_SALT=$REACT_APP_PAYMENT_PAGE_STORAGE_ENCRYPT_SALT --build-arg REACT_APP_PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID=$REACT_APP_PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID -f ./Dockerfile-stage .
              - docker push evoeccdocker/membership_front:stage
            caches:
              - docker
              - nodecustom
              - yarn
    master: #MASTER
        - step:
            name: Build docker
            image: node:16-alpine
            size: 2x
            deployment: Production
            services:
              - docker
            script:
              - export NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8192
              - yarn install
              - yarn build
              - docker login -u $DOCKER_HUB_ID -p $DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD
              - docker build -t evoeccdocker/membership_front:prod --build-arg REACT_APP_AUTH=$REACT_APP_AUTH --build-arg REACT_APP_MEMBERSHIP=$REACT_APP_MEMBERSHIP --build-arg REACT_APP_PAYMENT=$REACT_APP_PAYMENT --build-arg REACT_APP_APPLICATION_ID=$REACT_APP_APPLICATION_ID --build-arg REACT_APP_APPLICATION_KEY=$REACT_APP_APPLICATION_KEY --build-arg REACT_APP_TINYMCE=$REACT_APP_TINYMCE --build-arg REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=$REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID --build-arg REACT_APP_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS=$REACT_APP_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS --build-arg REACT_APP_PAYMENT_PAGE_STORAGE_ENCRYPT_SALT=$REACT_APP_PAYMENT_PAGE_STORAGE_ENCRYPT_SALT --build-arg REACT_APP_PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID=$REACT_APP_PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID -f ./Dockerfile-prod .
              - docker push evoeccdocker/membership_front:prod
            caches:
              - docker
              - nodecustom
              - yarn
definitions:
  caches:
    nodecustom: ./node_modules
    yarn: /usr/local/share/.cache/yarn

Does anyone know how to fix this? Or is there an easy way to find out which package or plugin is causing this peak of memory usage?

There is not enough information in the question to give an exact cause and solution. Therefore, you have to enable additional logging and debug messages, to show more info about what is happening during the build process.
You need to continuously monitor what happens to the memory usage inside the Docker container, and also display which processes are running during the build.
So before the 'yarn build' command, add something like this:
- while true; do ps -aux && sleep 5; done &
- while true; do echo "Memory usage in megabytes:" && echo $((`cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.memsw.usage_in_bytes | awk '{print $1}'`/1048576)) && sleep 2; done &
- yarn build

This will display the memory usage every 2 seconds, and show which processes are running. This will happen inside the Docker container, in real-time, during a CI/CD build.
From there, you can check which command is using too much memory. Perhaps it's creating too many parallel threads or processes, or it's opening too many files at the same time. Try to find a flag to reduce the number of threads or processes that it creates.
More info here: How can I find a memory leak (or what is taking up so much memory) in ParcelJS?
